# JavaScript target question

Tags: javascript

Here is some code I don't understand, but I know it opens the link in THE SAME WINDOW. I like it to open in BLANK NEW WINOWS... what to add/modify?

```
[some code before]
_.addEvent(b, 'click', function (e, i) {
document.location.href = (('undefined' !== typeof i) ? i: e.target).getAttribute('flickrshow-u')});_.addEvent(b, 'load', function (e, i) {
[some code after]
```

I tried to add `e.target = "_blank";` before document, but no luck!
I got this error: setting a property that has only a getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL assigned to `document.location.href` will open in the same window. If you pass this same url to `window.open`, it will open in a new window/tab.

You can read [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/linking_famsupp_120.html) about the different parameters `window.open` takes.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `document.location.href`, you need to use `window.open` to  open a page in new window.

**More Info:**

- http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that work :

```
_.addEvent(b, 'click', function (e, i) { var linkk = (('undefined' !== typeof i) ? i: e.target).getAttribute('flickrshow-u');
                    window.open(linkk, "_blank");
```